# How come "sudo -Eualice" accepts the user argument when there is no space between?

Tags: arguments, command-line-interface, sudo, flags

If I run the following command: `sudo -Eualice whoami`

How come the command accepts the user argument when there is no space between the flag and the argument? I'd expect `-Eualice` to be interpreted as `-E -u -a -l -i -c -e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo -Eualice` is just following the usual convention for Unix command lines.  If an option takes an option-argument (like the `-u` option takes a *`username`* option-argument) then the option-argument can be separated from the option letter by whitespace (as in `-u alice`) or it can immediately follow the option letter without whitespace (as in `-ualice`).

There's a similar convention for options that don't take arguments.  An option that does not take arguments (like `-E` in this case) can be followed by whitespace, or it can be followed immediately by another option, and that non-whitespace sequence can continue for multiple options.  This is what lets you do things like `ls -lsatr` rather than having to type `ls -l -s -a -t -r`.

In your example you have both of those skip-the-whitespace variants in action at the same time. The `-E` is immediately followed by the `u` option which is immediately followed by `u`'s `alice` option-argument.

No further options can follow the option-argument without whitespace because that would be ambiguous, so if you wanted to add a `-P` option then you'd have to write:

```
sudo -Eualice -P whoami
```

or you could write the `-P` somewhere before the `-u`:

```
sudo -EPualice whoami
```

which is more convenient than having to write:

```
sudo -E -P -u alice whoami
```

However, if you were writing the command in a context where it might have to be read by other people (say, in a shell script that other people will use and maintain) then you might decide to use the long fully-whitespace separated version because it is clearer for humans to read.